# Hipervinculo a una celda especifica de otro archivo excel

Tags: excel

Me gustaría conocer si con la formula HIPERVINCULO puedo apuntar dinamicamente o estaticamente a una celda especifica de otro archivo excel. La idea es que el mismo se abra y me lleve a la celda de interés.

Comment: Este enlace creo que te servirá para lo que comentas: https://computerhoy.com/video/como-crear-hipervinculos-celdas-hojas-excel-33571 pero no lo hace con la fórmula HIPERVINCULO.

Comment: Saludos, pero la idea es usar la formula de HIPERVINCULO.....!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar `HIPERVINCULO` de excel en el archivo `miIndice.xlsx` hay que tener en consideración:

- El Sistema Operativo (SO) y La ruta
- El nombre del archivo con su extensión = `miReferencia.xlsx`
- El nombre de la hoja de `miReferencia.xlsx`  = `Hoja1`
- El nombre de la celda de `Hoja1` = `B1`

Escribimos lo siguiente en la `Hoja3` celda `C5` del archivo `miIndice.xlsx`:

**SO: Windows**

```
=HIPERVINCULO("[C:\miRuta\miReferencia.xlsx]Hoja1!B1";B1)
```

**SO: macOS**

```
=HIPERVINCULO("[Macintosh HD:miRuta:miReferencia.xlsx]Hoja1!B1";B1)
```

### Consideraciones

Se ha empleado `B1` y `C5` a pesar de ser archivos diferentes, porque emplear el mismo nombre de celda ocasionará una referencia circular, aquí explican más sobre como [Quitar o permitir una referencia circular](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/quitar-o-permitir-una-referencia-circular-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123)

Si quisieras un nombre `miVinculo` en la celda `C5` dónde va ir la función `HIPERVINCULO` se antepone lo siguiente en `B1` tanto en **windows** como **macO**S:

```
=HIPERVINCULO(...rutaWindows o rutaMacOs ...;"miVinculo"&B1)
```

Finalmente en **OneDrive**, la versión gratuita permite hacer lo expuesto con la salvedad de que por el momento no se puede referenciar la `hoja` que se necesita, por tanto nos enviará a la primera hoja que se encuentra en la parte inferior izquierda, se puede leer más sobre esto en [Excel: Hipervínculos locales ahora apuntan a OneDrive](https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/msoffice/forum/msoffice_drive-mso_winother-mso_365hp/excel-hiperv%C3%ADnculos-locales-ahora-apuntan-a/32721548-9f0e-44ea-92ed-5fd73fe3f8ed)

Answer (score 0):

Sí se puede

```
=HIPERVINCULO("C:\Compras\prueba.xlsx"; H12)
```

Muestra la celda H12 del libro "prueba.xlsx" guardado en C:\Compras

Comment: Probe. Abre el archivo pero no me muestra la celda de interes. Ese es exactamente el problema que tengo. Deseo aperturar el archivo excel y que me coloque en la celda que especifique.

Comment: Debería funcionar correctamente. No tiene misterio.  Echa un vistazo a: https://support.office.com/es-es/article/hipervinculo-funci%C3%B3n-hipervinculo-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f